# C++ Get Bit Shift from Enum Value

Tags: c++, enums, bit-shift

Let's say I have an enum which is used for flags, i.e.

```
enum Flags { Flag1 = 1 << 0, Flag2 = 1 << 1, Flag3 = 1 << 2 };
```

If I am given a `Flags` value, I would like to know what the bit shift of the value is. Essentially, for `Flag1` I would like to return 0, for `Flag2` I would like to return 1, etc. Can anyone think of a way to do this other than using a function with a `switch` statement.

I am wanting this because I have an array of data and the return value of a function is one of the elements of this array. Which element to return is dependent on which flag is passed to the function.

**I would like a more concise way of doing the following.** Especially one where if I modify the enum I do not need to go back and modify this function.

```
myobj* objects[3] = { obj1, obj2, obj3 };

myobj* GetObj(Flags FlagValue)
{
    switch(FlagValue)
    {
        case Flag1:
            return objects[0];
        case Flag2:
            return objects[1];
        case Flag3:
            return objects[2];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is a function that counts trailing zeros in your enum values. There are quite a few methods that can do this (see https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZerosOnRightLinear), but most modern platforms typically provide a dedicated CPU instruction that does exactly that. Since the language has no corresponding operator, access to that instruction is only available through non-standard compiler-specific means, like `__builtin_ctz` in GCC or `_BitScanReverse` in MSVC.

However, if you are exclusively working with compile-time values a better C++ solution would be something along the lines of

```
template <unsigned N> struct ctz {
  static const unsigned value = ctz<N - 1>::value + 1;
};

template <> struct ctz<1> {
  static const unsigned value = 0;
};

template <> struct ctz<0>; // Left undefined

...
cout << ctz<Flag2>::value << endl;
```

Comment: I settled on `_BitScanReverse`. It seems to be the most concise and best performance. Since this is something which is potentially called often, I like the non-looping method. Even if there is a loop internal to `_BitScanReverse` it is probably optimized better than me writing a while loop with error checking.

Answer (score 2):

The most concise (and probably correct) way is to re-engineer the design. The 'flag' is not really a flag - it's an index, so code in terms of an index.

```
enum Index { I1, I2, I3, INDEX_COUNT };

myobj* objects[INDEX_COUNT] = { obj1, obj2, obj3 };

myobj* GetObj(Index i)
{
    assert(i < INDEX_COUNT);
    return objects[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
int iFlag = (int)FlagValue;
int ix = 0;
while (iFlag > 1) {
  ix++;
  iFlag = iFlag >> 1;
}
return objects[ix];
```

To be safe, add checks for illegal input like `FlagValue <= 0` or `FlagValue >= (sizeof(objects) / sizeof(objects[0]))`.